# ERROR in this.symbolResolver.getSymbolByModule is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-cli, package.json

I am developing an angular 2 app however came across the following error: RROR in this.symbolResolver.getSymbolByModule is not a function. I detect a mismatch? searched online, but none of the solutions work for me. Please can you help?

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3
node: 6.10.3
os: darwin x64
@angular/common: 2.4.10
@angular/compiler: 2.4.10
@angular/core: 2.4.10
@angular/forms: 2.4.10
@angular/http: 2.4.10
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.3
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.10
@angular/router: 3.4.10
@angular/animations: 4.1.1
@angular/cli: 1.0.2
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.1.1
@angular/platform-server: 4.1.1
```

However in my package.json it reads

```
    "@angular/animations": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "^4.1.1"
```

Comment: have you seen this: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3674?

Comment: hang on, you are using angular cli 1.0.2  in package.json but your global is 1.0.0-beta.28.3 ??? please follow this: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli

Comment: Hi Ahmed, I have updated the angular cli following the steps in this link: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli. Now im getting "*bash: /Users/<username>/.node/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng: No such file or directory*" via the "npm start" command

Comment: I have fixed the problem, i found out there was a mismatch between my dependencies and dev dependencies, i corrected this and followed the same steps here: github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli  and it worked thanks!!